# Oracle: Handling a field named COMMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00936

I have a table with a field named COMMENT, which appears to be a reserved word.

Using SQLDeveloper, if I try:

```
select
  [COMMENT],
  another_field
FROM table_created_by_idiot_developer
```

I get

```
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

How can I access this field in my select in SQL Developer? (Is this a problem with SQL Developer, or should field not be named COMMENT in oracle?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `"COMMENT"` instead of `[COMMENT]`. This is alternate syntax commonly accepted by various DBMSes. I have used this syntax to refer to columns having dots or UTF8 characters in their names in SQLite.

Comment: More to the point, "..." is the correct syntax for delimiting an identifier in Oracle.

Comment: Yes, `[]` is the true alternate syntax actually.

Comment: Using reserved words for identifiers/objects is a nightmare - yes, you can create a schema, table, column all named "TABLE" - but you most definitely should not. Just makes things harder for yourself.